# ld and lld use only paths I input

Tags: linker, ld, lld

I am trying to cross compile for my raspberry pi, unfortunately the pi has an older version of libstdc++ than my build machine and when I try to run my executable it says "./<exe_name>: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./<exe_name>). I've gotten it working by using "-static", but really I'd like to be able to tell both ld (the gcc linker) and lld (the clang linker) "Only look in these paths for *any* libraries" it keeps finding the system one and linking against it. I've rsynced the raspberry pi's /usr/lib and /lib directores over to the host machine and I'd like to say "use /path_to_raspberry_pi_rsync/lib and /path_to_raspberry_pi_rsync/usr/lib" only.

Bonus points for getting ld and lld to tell me what path it's using when it tries to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to tell both ld (the gcc linker) and lld (the clang linker) "Only look in these paths for any libraries"

Both will do that if you supply proper `-L/path/to/target/libraries` with sufficient contents.

> it keeps finding the system one and linking against it. I've rsynced the raspberry pi's /usr/lib and /lib directores over to the host machine and I'd like to say "use /path_to_raspberry_pi_rsync/lib and /path_to_raspberry_pi_rsync/usr/lib" only.

Your problem most likely stems from the fact that what you `rsync`ed are *runtime* libraries, not actual development libraries. So if e.g. `/path_to_raspberry_pi_rsync/usr/lib` contains `libstdc++.so.6`, but *doesn't* contain `libstdc++.so` symlink, then the linker will keep looking for `libstdc++.so.`, until it finds one in the system directory.

In *addition*, once you succeed limiting your link to just the "rsync"d libraries, it is likely that your link will fail with unresolved `libstdc++` symbols. That is because you need a *matching* set of headers and libraries.

Your best bet is to obtain a *proper* toolchain targeting your runtime environment.

> Bonus points for getting ld and lld to tell me what path it's using when it tries to link.

With `ld`, you can add `-Wl,-t` flag and it will tell you about each and every library and object file it opens. `lld` may support this flag as well.